# Is it possible to sort a table using an array in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, join

I need to sort a table using Laravel, and I have a "status_id" field where I cannot join another table, because the statuses are in an array.

The array:

```
$statuses = [
  1 => 'Active',
  2 => 'Suspended',
  3 => 'Inactive'
];
```

The Laravel query (joinArray doesn't exist, I need something like this):

```
Contact::select('id', 'name', 'status_id', 'status_name')
->joinArray($statuses, ['status_id'=>'status_name'])
->orderBy('status');
```

I need the ordering to be like this (in an alphabetical order):

```
* Active
* Inactive
* Suspended
```

But I receive this (according to the 'status_id' field):

```
* Active
* Suspended
* Inactive
```

Comment: if you have `status_name` column then why don't you sort it by `status_name`?

Comment: @RahulMeshram OP wants to sort in specific order. Sorting by `status_name` would return **Active, Inactive, Suspended** when they actually want **Active, Suspended, Inactive**.

Comment: I think you read question wrong. Can you please re-read again?

Comment: @RahulMeshram I need to receive a column such as 'status_name' after the join

Comment: Receive? Your requirement still not clear mate!

Comment: @RahulMeshram I need to JOIN an array rather than another table, so I can sort by 'status_name', which is a column I would receive after the join.

Answer (score 0):

The following is untested however should work.

```
Contact::select('id', 'name', 'status_id', 'status_name')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function($query) {
       $statuses = [
          1 => 1, //Active in first position
          2 => 3, //Suspended in third position
          3 => 2  //Inactive in second position
       ];
       return $statuses[$query->status_id];
    });
```

It would be much easier if you added the statuses into the database and just created a relation.

Comment: That worked!!!
I also had to figure out how to paginate it, but I've found a solution on this page [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-paginate-laravel-collection]

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is that the array has to be constant. If someone makes any change in the array, the order may be wrong.
Chances are that my array will not change at all or only once or twice ever, so I will use it.

Comment: Thanks Arnon. Feel free to mark as the solution. Indeed this would be better if the statuses were in the database, that way you could just set up a relationship.